# Dual boot ubuntu 20.04 / win10...(bit of a mess)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

Attempting to install ubuntu (20.04) dual boot win10 on a newly refurb  Dell E6520 i7 8GB DDR3 RAM 128 SSD Win10 Pro 64

Got all the way to installation type & no option to install along side win10

Attempted the something else option however believe this is where the problems started as the partition options quite confusing

Thought I might try to start over however win10 now says "no operating system"

Scoured many very informative related postings however still a bit too much of a noob to be able to utilize

Any assist greatly appreciated

Dave

Comment: Cannot boot into windows  (no operating system)

Comment: Glad you got it figured out! I'm flagging this for closure as a duplicate (since your answer is just a link to boot repair) See: [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Comment: Problem de jour ....appears I set rufus to format gpt/uefi for my legacy bios  ....Just cant seem to get  rufus configured correctly ...the adventure continues  any suggestions welcome

Comment: OK that comment does not add clarity and just muddies the waters.  The default settings in Rufus are appropriate for installation media. However if the settings are overwhelming or confusing, I suggest using [etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) as it is straightforward and uncomplicated and very hard to mess up since there aren't as many niche options you don't need for the purpose of creating installation media. If you still have problems, ask another question. We need clear unambiguous details about the steps you take and the results you are getting. Don't leave out anything.

Comment: Understood.....Appreciate the suggestion                                                                                   as previously indicated, a bit of a noob & attempting to provide as much succinct detail as possible

Comment: To set up dual boot config you'll first need to make sure that Windows is bootable and working. In order to get the guided "install alongside windows" option, you need enough unpartitioned free space for the Ubuntu installer to create a partition and file system during installation. Finally you'll need to boot the USB in the same mode Windows is installed. Etcher creates media that can be booted either way.   Most Windows installations are UEFI, not legacy/BIOS. (UEFI≠Legacy/BIOS)